# Docker desktop in wsl2 not starting

Tags: wsl-2, docker-desktop

I use docker desktop in wsl2 (Ubuntu 22.04) in Windows 11 Enterprise.
Windows is up to date.
I am using wsl2

Starting today, Docker desktop is not starting. it just stays in "Starting docker engine" screen.

I have already uninstalled docker, downloaded the docker-desktop client again, and reinstalled it. But doesn't work.

This is the screen where it hungs
[image]

And the Docker desktop installed info
[image]

Any guess what could be the problem ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
The latest version of Docker Desktop ( 4.18 ) removed the following entry from hosts file

127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal

adding this entry again to the hosts file and restarting the computer, fixes the issue

Comment: What is the path of the hosts file (Windows) ? [Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/784196/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-windows-10-or-11/) they're suggesting `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, is that correct? There I found the hosts file, it already contained `127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal`, shall I still add `127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal` ?

Comment: Just noticed that it contained `192.168.???.?? host.docker.internal` (I masked the IP here), what is correct? 127.0.0.1 or this specific IP address?